# Parse - updating big list in for loop?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to update 1000 items each time with some value in specific column in my DB

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> searchQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("PhoneBook");
searchQuery.whereDoesNotExist("search");
searchQuery.setLimit(1000);
public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                for(ParseObject contact:results){
                     contact.put("search","someNewValue");
                     contact.saveInBackground();
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
```

Actually only 200-300 updated even i run on 1000 items.
is there any limit of fast saveInBackground()?

should i use `saveEvantually()`?

Answer (score 1):

You should store all object in a List and then call `saveAllInBackground`. Try like this :

```
        searchQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

        @Override           
        public void done(List<ParseObject> results, ParseException e) {
                    if (e == null) {
                        ArrayList<ParseObject> phoneObjectList=new ArrayList<ParseObject>();

                        for(ParseObject contact:results){
                             contact.put("search","someNewValue");

                             phoneObjectList.add(contact);
                        }
                        ParseObject.saveAllInBackground(phoneObjectList, new SaveCallback() {

                            @Override
                            public void done(ParseException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                if(e==null){
                                    Log.d(TAG, "saved successfully");
                                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                }else{
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Error in saving view count :"+e.getMessage());
                                }
                            }
                        });


                    } else {

                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: thank you this is good solution, any way you can see the error i got from parse down here.

Answer (score 0):

I got an email from parse:

> Your app ... recently exceeded 75% of your plan's request
>   limit of 30 requests/second. Additional requests to Parse exceeding
>   the rate of 30 requests/second will be dropped, returning an error
>   with error code 155.

saving data might exceed the exceeded 30 requests/second.

so, saving such of big amount of data should take in consideration...

this is how it looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Been there, done that. `saveAllInBackground()` is crappy. I had to use loop for each object with plain `saveInBackground()` without callback. And yes - 200,300 save objects from 1000 is normal (for that service). It's not designed to work with batch saves I suppose. And yes - it's easy to exceed limit with saving that much.